# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : Windows authentication returns user identity as Null

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with Windows authentication. I need to get the 'default user' running the application and invoke another query subsequently. The code works ok from Swagger (VS 2022) and when running from Postman or Angular 15, it returns null. What is missing?

But, when running from Postman, the 'Auth Header' I selected NTLM and and that will force a userid/pwd to enter and it works.

Already looked at these links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

[WEB API - Authorize at controller or action level (no authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751104/web-api-authorize-at-controller-or-action-level-no-authentication)

`launchSettings.json`:

```
{
    "profiles": {
        "PTMWeb": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "swagger",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "dotnetRunMessages": true,
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5170"
        },
        "IIS Express": {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "swagger",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    },
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
        "iisSettings": {
            "windowsAuthentication": true,
            "anonymousAuthentication": false,
            "iisExpress": {
                "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5170",
                "sslPort": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
                {
                    jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                });


builder.Services.AddDbContext<PtmDBContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ptm- 
              connection"));
                });

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default 
             policy.
                    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
                });

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// Set the JSON serializer options
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
                    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                    options.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
                });

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                        policy =>
                        {
                            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                            policy.AllowAnyMethod();

                        });
                });

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                });

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpC;

    public UserController(IHttpContextAccessor _httpC, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        httpC = _httpC;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
            
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("GetDefaultUser")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<GetUserDto>>> GetDefaultUser()
    {
        string? _name = httpC.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        if (_name != null)   //returns null here
        {
            var slashIndex = _name.IndexOf("\\");
            var _userId = slashIndex > -1
                            ? _name.Substring(slashIndex + 1)
                            : _name.Substring(0, _name.IndexOf("@"));

            var result = await _userRepository.GetUser(_userId);

            if (result == null) 
                 return NotFound();

            return Ok(result);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular you should use `withCredentials`.

```
method() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/GetUser`, { withCredentials: true });
}
```

Comment: no luck from angular :

Comment: still no luck.  Cors err :  as been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is  '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.